# After an option from the JComboBox is selected, the text of a JLabel should be changed

Tags: java, button, jbutton, jlabel

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener
  {
    JLabel question, res, reply;
JCheckBox three, fortyThree, one, eightySeven, nine, ten;
    JButton submit;
    JComboBox<String> box;
String option[];
    
    public void main()
    {
      JFrame frm = new JFrame("GUI INTRO");
      JPanel content = new JPanel();
      frm.add(content);

      String option[] = {"inches to centimeters", "miles to feet", "kilograms to pounds", "cups to fluid ounces"};
      box = new JComboBox<>(option);
      box.setBounds(50,80,90,30);
       reply = new JLabel(" ");
      content.add(box);
      content.add(reply);
  
         frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
      frm.setSize(700,700);
      frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
      
      frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frm.setVisible(true);
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(option[0].isSelected()) // Error occurs here
    reply.setText("1 inch = 2.54 centimeters");
} 
      public static void main(String[] args){
        Main frame = new Main();
        frame.main();
      }
    }
```

When the option "inches to centimeters" is chosen the JLabel 'reply' should be changed to "1 inch = 2.54 centimeters". The issue is that I don't know haw to call it properly. I called it by stating if(option[0].isSelected()) and since "inches to centimeters" is option[0] I would expect it to work. I'm unsure if you can even use .isSelected() for locating the JComboBox option selected.

Answer (score 0):

It would be preferable to implement `ItemListener` (you can implement `ActionListener` too) and then in the handler:

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
   if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
      reply.setText(event.getItem().toString());
   }
}
```